# Yii2 advanced on docker

Tags: php, docker, yii2

I have yii2 advanced application on docker, mysql db does not work.

My docker-compose:

```
db:
  image: 'mysql:latest'
  volumes:
      - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
  ports:
      - '3306:3306'
  restart: always
  environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
     MYSQL_DATABASE: database
```

db in yii2:

```
return => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=database',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
```

When i go on my local folder with yii2 and go `php yii migrate` i see `Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client'`

How fix my pronblem?

All code https://github.com/k0v4back/docker-yii2

Comment: Is the application also running in a Docker container?

Comment: If your mysql and php are two different containers, then you should write the host in dsn as the mysql ip address or host name.

Comment: In my docker-compose I have php-fpm and php-cli, 
Should I connect with them? It is my code https://github.com/k0v4back/docker-yii2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created this answer based on your [docker-compose.yml file](https://github.com/k0v4back/docker-yii2/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)

Create new bridge network in your docker-compose.yml file:

```
networks:
  my-new-network:
    driver: bridge
```

It's important to connect all your containers to one network(bridge) to allow communication between them.

Add each your container to the new network:

```
db:
  image: 'mysql:latest'
  volumes:
      - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
  ports:
      - '3306:3306'
  restart: always
  environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
     MYSQL_DATABASE: database
  networks:
     - my-new-network
```

After these changes check if the containers can communicate(send a ping from one to the other - use container names):

From nginx container:

```
ping db
```

if you don't have `ping` command, install iputils:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install iputils-ping
```

If everything works well - change your Yii DB connection configuration:

```
return => [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=db;port=3306;dbname=database', // change IP here to database container name
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
],
```

I think this should help to solve your problem. **Take care of communication between containers** :)

---

Ensure also that the database can accept external connections. Default mysql configuration block external connections, so you should check your mysql configuration and [add new user](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html) on which you can log in "from outside"(from external hosts/networks):

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

mysql root user has disabled remote connections by default. [More you can read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)

Logs will tell you much more :) https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/

---

I forked your repository: https://github.com/raciniewski/docker-yii2

1. Build and run all containers `docker-compose up --build`

[image]

[image]

2. Send ping to `db` container from other container in your new `my-new-network` network:

[image]
[image]

3. Done - containers can communicate

Comment: When I start `docker-compose exec nginx ping db`, I see `Some networks were defined but are not used by any service: ipam
ping: db: Name or service not known`. How to fix this?

Comment: remove `ipam: driver: default` from networks definition - my bad, you don't need this: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ipam

Comment: Now I  have `ping: db: Name or service not known` when go docker-compose exec nginx ping db.

Comment: it should work, I tested it. Delete all containers and images, restart the docker service and rebuild the entire project (I added some screenshots to the answer)

Comment: Thank you for help!

Comment: Happy to help :)